# Assembly program that writes an array to a disk file

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I'm trying to write an doubleword array to a disk file using `CreateOutputFile`, `WriteToFile` and `CloseFile` Irvine32 procedures. Here is my code.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

     count = 45 
     BUFFER_SIZE = 188
     filename BYTE "Fibonacci.txt",0
     fileHandle DWORD ?
     array DWORD 47 DUP(?)
     num1 = 1
     num2 = 1
     temp1 DWORD ?
     temp2 DWORD ?
.code

     main PROC
     mov edx,OFFSET filename
     call CreateOutputFile

     mov fileHandle,eax
     mov esi,0
     mov array[esi],num1
     mov eax,array[esi]
     mov temp1,eax
     add esi,4 
     mov array[esi],num2
     mov eax,array[esi]
     mov temp2,eax
     add esi,4
     mov ecx, count

L1:

     mov eax,0
     mov ebx,0
     mov eax,temp1
     mov ebx,temp2
     add eax,ebx
     mov array[esi],eax
     mov temp1,ebx
     mov temp2,eax
     add esi,4
     loop L1

     mov eax,fileHandle
     mov edx,OFFSET array
     mov ecx,BUFFER_SIZE
     call WriteToFile

     mov eax,fileHandle
     call CloseFile
     exit
main ENDP

END main
```

After I debugging it every time, a text file is created successfully, but it turns to be some unrecognizable codes in the text file. I think it should have been the array shown in hexadecimal.

I really don't know where I make mistakes. Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you would expect it to be "shown in hexadecimal", since you don't show any code to do that. There may be something in Kip Irvine's include file to do that - poke around in it (or RTFM). If not, it isn't too difficult to do...

Comment: I agree with Frank. Google yourself the mov al, number; sbb al, 69h; das; trick, that will make it even easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

The "unrecognizable codes" are 188 bytes that represent 47 values in the CPU internal format called "DWORD". The file is a memory dump of `array DWORD 47 DUP(?)`. For a human readable format, e.g. decimal strings, they have to be converted - one by one inside the Fibonacci loop (L1) or with a new loop (ladder is shown below as L2). The WinApi contains a function which can be used as conversion routine: [`wsprintf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms647550.aspx). Since the Irvine32 library declares this function, it can be used without further circumstances.

Example:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

    count = 45
    BUFFER_SIZE = 188
    filename BYTE "Fibonacci.txt",0
    fileHandle DWORD ?
    array DWORD 47 DUP(?)
    num1 = 1
    num2 = 1
    temp1 DWORD ?
    temp2 DWORD ?

    decimalstring BYTE 16 DUP(0)    ; String for WriteFile
    fmt BYTE "%u",13,10,0           ; Format string for wsprintf ("%u\r\n")

.code

main PROC

    mov edx,OFFSET filename
    call CreateOutputFile

    mov fileHandle,eax
    mov esi,0
    mov array[esi],num1
    mov eax,array[esi]
    mov temp1,eax
    add esi,4
    mov array[esi],num2
    mov eax,array[esi]
    mov temp2,eax
    add esi,4
    mov ecx, count

L1:
    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,0
    mov eax,temp1
    mov ebx,temp2
    add eax,ebx
    mov array[esi],eax
    mov temp1,ebx
    mov temp2,eax
    add esi,4
    loop L1

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array     ; Number of elements (DWORD's) in array
    mov esi, 0                  ; First index
L2:
    push ecx                    ; Preserve loop counter

    ;convert number to string
    push array[esi]             ; Argument for format string
    push OFFSET fmt             ; Pointer to format string ("%d")
    push OFFSET decimalstring   ; Pointer to buffer for output
    call wsprintf               ; Irvine32.inc / Smallwin.inc / User.lib / User.dll
    mov ecx, eax                ; Length of the stored string into ECX for WriteToFile
    add esp, (3*4)              ; CCALL calling function! Adjust the stack.

    mov eax, fileHandle
    mov edx, OFFSET decimalstring
    call WriteToFile

    pop ecx                     ; Restore loop counter
    add esi, 4                  ; Next DWORD
    loop L2

    mov eax,fileHandle
    call CloseFile
    exit
main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but still, to view the data you wrote on the file you need to view the HEX code of the file by using a HEX Editor tool. i tried debugging your code and viewed it with hex edit and your array was there.
You can download Hexedit from here : http://www.hexedit.com/
or use any other tool that will allow you to view file in hex mode.